# Powershell incremental number at start of string

Tags: variables, powershell, event-log

Attempting to increment the **start** of a string with a number.

```
foreach ($var in $variables) {
New-EventLog -computername $PC -LogName $var -source $var
}
```

I wish to increment $var with a number, so the result is like so:
$var = 1Server
$var = 2Server
etc etc.

How do I add in incremental number at the beginning of $var in my foreach statement?

I tried with:

```
$a = 1
foreach ($var in $variables) {
New-EventLog -computername $PC -LogName ($a++, $var) -source $var
}
```

But no dice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the format operator `-f` to insert the value of `$a` in the parameter for the Logname

```
$a = 1
foreach ($var in $variables) {
    New-EventLog -computername $PC -LogName ("{0}$var" -f $a++) -source $var
}
```

Comment: This worked EXACTLY the way I wanted it to. Thank you very much for the swift reply!

Will mark as answer when I can.